# mySQL SUM and Ordering

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

We have a table which inserts a row each day and updates it with data.

I have the following query to get the total amount of clicks from the table:

```
SELECT SUM(`total_clicks`) AS clicks, `last_updated` FROM `reporting` WHERE `unique_id` = 'xH7' ORDER BY `last_updated` DESC
```

When pulling this info from the database, it is pulling the correct total amount of clicks but the last_updated field is from the first row (yesterday) not the new row inserted today.

How can I go about getting the most recent last_updated field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the most recent date, use `MAX` to select it:

```
SELECT SUM(total_clicks) as clicks, MAX(last_updated) AS last_updated
FROM reporting
WHERE unique_id = 'xH7'
```

The problem with your version is that `ORDER BY` happens *after* aggregating, and aggregation selects non-aggregate columns from arbitrary rows in the table.

Answer (score 1):

If you have only one row per day, then you don't need `sum()`.  Does the following do what you want?

```
SELECT `total_clicks` AS clicks, `last_updated`
FROM `reporting`
WHERE `unique_id` = 'xH7'
ORDER BY `last_updated` DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Your query is an aggregation query that adds up all the clicks in the table.  Because it returns only one row, the `order by` isn't doing anything.

Comment: No we need the sum as we are grabbing the data for this campaign as a whole. We need the total amount of clicks for this unique id and the latest last_updated field.